# How can I make a slow-ish `system` call in a statusline without corrupting the display?

Tags: external-command, statusline, performance

I wrote a quick snippet of VimL to display, in my statusline, the type of the currently focused Haskell expression
It looks like this ([click for better quality (as gfy)](https://gfycat.com/EnlightenedShimmeringHoiho)):

[image: Screen-capture of a cursor moving around a vim buffer, with the statusline constantly updating to show the type of the selected expression]

I've included the code below,
but the only important part is the `system` call.
The call takes about 0.04 s to execute,
which is fine with me;
there's really no noticeable delay.

However, what does bother me greatly
is that if I send a key event while the system call is running,
the key is echoed to the display
and overwrites a character.
Of course, it doesn't actually modify the buffer,
and hitting `<C-L>` is sufficient to fix it,
but this happens whenever I'm pressing keys rapidly in sequence
or holding down a key,
so writing `<C-L>` all the time is very frustrating.

(Worse, it means that I can't trust my own eyes!)

How can I solve this problem?

---

To reproduce this, create a file with ten or so lines
(like `10Ohello<Esc>`) and save it as `sample.txt`.
Save the below text block as `sample.vimrc`.
Then run `vim sample.txt -u sample.vimrc` and hold down `j`;
you should see a bunch of `j`s appear.
Hit `<C-L>` to clear them.

Here's `sample.vimrc`:

```
set nocompatible

set statusline=%{SlowOutput()}
function! SlowOutput()
    silent call system("sleep 0.1")
    return "I'm awake; I'm awake!"
endfunction

set laststatus=2

" tried with and without this (I would *very* much prefer to keep it on):
" set lazyredraw
```

---

The actual code I'm using,
in case I'm missing something important
or you just want the code for yourself, follows
(it depends on [bling/vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) and [bitc/vim-hdevtools](https://github.com/bitc/vim-hdevtools)):

```
let g:airline_section_gutter = "%{HaskellCursorType()}%="
function! HaskellCursorType()
    if &l:ft != "haskell"
        return ""
    else
        let l:file = expand("%")
        if l:file == ''
            return ""
        endif
        if !filereadable(l:file)
            return ""
        endif
        let l:line = line('.')
        let l:col = col('.')
        let l:cmd = hdevtools#build_command('type', shellescape(l:file) . ' ' . l:line . ' ' . l:col)
        silent let l:output = system(l:cmd)
        let l:lines = split(l:output, '\n')
        if len(l:lines) == 0
            return "(no type)"
        endif
        return matchstr(l:lines[0], '"\zs[^"]\+\ze"')
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: (Sorry if the tags are way off—feel free to edit.)

Comment: What happens if you clear the screen in vimscript, right at the end of the statusline update (after the `system` call)? Also, do you have a recent Vim version - newer versions may have that graphical glitch solved. Also, ideally you would never run lengthy operations to update the statusline; some other operation should update a variable, which the statusline should read when it needs to update itself.

Comment: I don't have this problem in xterm with Vim 7.4.712. Which Vim version and terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: I also do not have this problem (Vim 7.4.1089) (neither in vim in urxvt or gvim).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I'm using Vim 7.4 with patches 1–52 (2013 Aug 10 build; standard from Mint 17/Ubuntu 14.04 LTS repo), and can reproduce on GNOME Terminal 3.6.2 and XTerm(297).

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg The problem does not occur for me in gvim (same version), but I don't use gvim.

Comment: @VanLaser A `redraw!` works but causes equally distracting flicker that means I can't actually see the statusline while navigating (rather defeating the purpose). A `redraw` doesn't seem to do much.

Comment: @VanLaser Thanks for the advice; the reason I put this in the statusline was because I wanted it to update every time the status line needs to be updated—e.g., because the user moved the selection—and just putting the computation in the statusline itslef seemed like the most foolproof way. Should I use something like the `CursorMoved` augroup? Would the  autocmd action then need to call `redrawstatusline` or something?

Comment: Indeed, and I suggest to use `CursorHold` / `CursorHoldI` events to update the variable, if possible. IIRC this is the method used by tagbar.vim (which also has an vim-airline extension).

Comment: @VanLaser Sounds like a good idea—but `CursorHold` only updates every 4000ms (and I don't want to decrease `updatetime` to 100ms because that would induce oodles of swap file writes), while `CursorMove` causes way more lag than just updating directly in the statusline, and also doesn't completely fix the display issue (though it's a bit better). Any suggestions for asynchronous actions or something like that?

Comment: You could probably integrate your work with Shougo's VimProc plugin; but I suggested `CursorHold` precisely because it's triggered only after a "still" period. This allows for smooth movement and a lazy statusbar information update. You could also disable swap files, lower the timeout and rely on some version control software ...

Comment: To anyone following this: [vim8](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/version8.txt) promises async commands, which may help.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this problem in other plugins as well (and some take a LOT more than 0.04 seconds).

The issue appears to be that Vim puts the terminal into "cooked" mode so that the command that is run can receive interrupt signals (from ctrl+c). This means that, for the duration of the command, your terminal is in line-editing mode. You can try this yourself by running, say, "sleep 5" in a system command and observe that wherever your cursor was when it was run, what you type starts there, and you can use backspace, ctrl+u, etc to edit the line. Whatever the line was when the command exits after your editing is then read by vim and processed.

The only Vim Proper ways to spawn an external program I can find (`:!cmd`, `:r!cmd`, and `system("cmd")`) all suffer this, though only system doesn't redraw the screen, but all will flicker with redrawing.

Neovim is doing some work for handling terminal programs, but that doesn't help if your target audience includes Vim (and I haven't kept up with it so I don't know where that stands)

Due to the architecture, I don't think there is a way around this in Vim proper. No matter how fast your external program runs, there is always a period of time where a character can enter the terminal while in cooked mode.

If you are willing to depend on one of the language extensions of Vim, you *could* use that to run your external command without changing the terminal mode.

For example:

```
:python import os
:python os.system("sleep 5")
```

with the result that the terminal freezes for 5 seconds while the command runs. The text you type will make it to Vim afterwards without any line editing by the terminal (e.g. backspaces , ctrl+u, etc. will be interpreted by vim and in order of characters typed).

The downsides of course are:

- adds an extra dependency to your plugin (python, perl, or whatever you use)
- There is no way from the terminal to interrupt the operation now (can have a hung terminal unless someone interrupts the program via other means, like a kill command in another shell or process manager. Any ctrl+c a user types will be interpreted by vim once the command ends)

The latter might be mitigated by adjusting the terminal settings yourself in, say, python prior to calling the external command. Be careful there, though.

Comment: Thank you. This is interesting. I will take another look at neovim. Unfortunately, the command sometimes (rarely) does hang when I've configured things wrong, so the `python` trick isn't an option, but it's very good to know about the difference between [cooked mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooked_mode) and raw mode.